# How to access custom control of a CoreAudio driver?

Tags: c++, macos, driver, core-audio

I'm creating a CoreAudio driver's configuration application, because it has some custom
parameters. I can access the default controls, like volume and mute, and another
properties, like channel number, with `AudioObjectGetPropertyData` and `AudioObjectSetPropertyData`. I'm not the developer
of the driver, but we are working together on this.

When creating a custom control (in the driver's side, not application's) with `IOAudioXXXControl::create()`, and given a custom control subtype I cant access it
from application. But if I create it with a "default" value (defined in headers), I can access it.

For example, creating the driver's control with:

```
control = IOAudioToggleControl::create(FALSE,
    kIOAudioControlChannelIDAll,
    0,0, 'phan',                             //'phan' is as kAudioToggleControlSubTypePhantomPower
    kIOAudioControlUsageCoreAudioProperty);
```

and, on the application, I ask if there is this control this way:

```
AudioObjectPropertyAddress pAddress;
pAddress.mSelector = 'phan';
pAddress.mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal;
pAddress.mElement =kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster;

if (AudioObjectHasProperty(device, &pAddress)) {
```

it returns OK.

But if I change `'phan'`to `'phaN'`, to create a custom control,
the device returns it does not have the control. I have tried setting
the controlID and mess around with the parameters of `create` function,
bu no success.

We have searched through Apple documentation, books like OS X and iOS Kernel
Programming etc. but the examples only show the creation of default controls,
like volume and mute, only saying it is possible creating custom commands.

Is there any error in the way I'm requesting the control? If I open AudioObject
Browser in HALLab I can see the control in both cases (with 'phan' and 'phaN').

Is some step missing in driver's code, application's code or both? Or is it not
possible to do things this way - and if so, any guideline will be appreciated.

Thanks!